# Virtualbox limitations

Tags: c++, linux, unix, virtualbox

I'm taking a course next semester which involves programming c++ in a Unix environment,
the course staff told us we should either work on our faculty computers (computer farm) or install ubuntu natively on our personal machines.

My idea was to install Linux on a virtual machine (with Windows 7 64 bit being the host) without making any damage to my system.

Are there any major limitations I should be aware of that have to do with, I don't know, compiling? linking? programming in c++?

Is there anything important that people who try to program inside a virtual environment should keep in mind?

Or is it just the same as programming in a standard environment?

Also, is there a difference in the compilation process? is there any chance that files will compile in my virtual environment but wont compile in my teachers' standard environment?

Bottom line, I don't want to end up with compilation errors, spending two days trying to fix it  and finding out its because I'm in a virtual environment.

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: Well, the hardware is different, as it has more abstraction layers, so you can't draw any conclusions about how interaction with, e.g. disk drives or printers, works on a computer with native Linux. Other than that, if the system you install on your VB is identical to what's on the server farm, it should act the same software-wise.

Comment: PS I'm doing a programming job now in Windows on a VirtualBox on my Linux system.

Comment: From the guest operating systems point of view, running in a virtual environment is not different from running directly on the hardware. There are no limitation except the ones you set yourself (e.g. max amount of memory, disk sizes, etc.). And unless you install and use special libraries yourself there should not be any problem giving the source to your teacher.

Comment: In fact, the virtual environment may even be better than the native one. I don't know _how_ they do this, but I'm running 64bit Linux under 32bit Windows, and it works... this includes having all AMD64 registers available when they aren't under the native system. It also includes a system timer with 100 nanosecond resolution when the native system timer has barely millisecond resolution. Magic.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try to do my projects in the VB and, for extra precaution, see if they work as they should on our faculty computers.